# Отказано в доступе по пути. Как исправить?

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Мне нужно скопировать всю папку с файлами и подпапками в другую папку.
Кому интересно или подозрительно: я делаю авто-бэкап браузера.
Есть подозрения что это из-за того что открыт процесс браузера. Но будет не очень красиво если я тупо напишу `Process.Kill("opera.exe")`. Мне нужно сделать кроссплатформенно, мало ли я в Firefox буду. Проблема в том, что я не знаю имена процессов ВСЕХ браузеров. Кхм кхм, ближе к делу.
Код:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("Other");
            string UserName = Environment.UserName;
            string start = "C:\\Users\\";
            string[] dirs = {start + UserName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\",
                start + UserName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\",
                start + UserName + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Opera Software\\Opera Stable\\",
                start + UserName + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\",
                start + UserName + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Cookies\\",
                start + UserName + "\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\INetCookies\\" };
for (UInt16 i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
            {
                backup(dirs[i]);
            }
static private void backup(string dir)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Move(dir, "Other\\");   // ТУТ ОШИБКА
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }
        }
```

Выбивает:

```
System.IO.IOException: "Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\"."
```

Права администратора на программу выданы в манифесте.

Comment: `Мне нужно скопировать всю папку` ... `Directory.Move(...)`?

Comment: @tym32167 , Ну да...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если хочется сделать бекап - нужно КОПИРОВАТЬ, а не ПЕРЕМЕЩАТЬ.
2. Если хочется именно что перемещать - то лучшим способом является вопрос можно ли закрыть программу, а потом уже если можно, то закрывать. Перемещать файлы программы пока она запущена явно нельзя.
3. Еще одна причина по которой может возникать подобная ошибка при копировании/перемещении - это отказ в доступе к файлам в принципе. То есть не хватает прав у пользователя. Категории `Program Files` и `AppData` являются категориями с ограниченным доступом и для копирования требуют прав администратора. То есть нужно проверять запускается ли программа от имени админа и просить перезапуска с нужными правми если нет.

Копирование директории со всеми субдиректориями и файлами:

```
//Создать идентичное дерево каталогов
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

//Скопировать все файлы. И перезаписать(если такие существуют)
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря странный бекап с перемещением файлов...попробуйте все таки копировать файлы. В этом случае даже если файл залочен процессом, читать его обычно не запрещают.

А вообще создание резервной копии с требованием закрыть приложение более оправдано, если бекап создается стороней программой. Так как файл может находится в неконсистентном состоянии в момент его копирования. А от такого бекапа может и толку то не будет. Хотя для браузеров возможно это не так актуально

Как копировать каталоги рассказано в официальном материале от MS https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories. Думаю вы там сможете найти полезную информацию по вашей проблеме

Comment: И всё таки как скопировать правильно? Любой способ. Переместить, скопировать, перезаписать. Как?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Добавил ссылку на документацию где раскрывается вопрос копирования каталогов